# How can assign leads from assignment rules?

Tags: apex, process-builder, flow

Can any one please make me understand what is happening in below class

```
public class AssignLeadsUsingAssignmentRules {    
 @InvocableMethod     
 public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)     {   
 Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();    
 dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;  
 Lead Leads=[select id from lead where lead.id in :LeadIds];  
 Leads.setOptions(dmo);      
  update Leads;  
 }   
 }
```

This class involved in one of process builder flows

[image]

[image]

The same condition we can give at lead assignment rule, then why did they invoked the apex class in process builder?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup --> Leads --> Lead Assignment Rules.

There should be an **Active** lead assignment rule defined there.  Based on the rules mentioned in that assignment rule, your Lead's are being assigned to that particular user/queue.

More on this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm)

Comment: The same condition we can give at lead assignment rule, then why did they invoked the apex class in process builder?